# Old Dell Inspiron 531 w/ XP. Can I run 14.04?

Tags: dual-boot, dell

I had an old Dell Inspiron 531 laying around and wanted to do something with it.

I decided to make it into a HTPC/DVR and light gaming rig(iRacing) mainly.

I was able to find a Dual core AMD64 XII 6000 125w 3.0ghz cpu for $20(Brand new) to take the place of the Sempron that's in it now.

I added 2 more gigs of ram for a total of 4. Also added 2gb GeForce610 graphics card to it, 160gig WD Hard Drive.

Now my question is will it run 14.04 or should I go ahead and buy Windows 7?

I will initially dual boot it with the XP pro that's on it now with hopes that I can eliminate XP all together.

Thanks for any help.

David

Comment: you can use live ubuntu to know how your system handles ubuntu..

Comment: It's been my experience that lack of memory and lack of 3D graphics are the only things that have stopped me from running Ubuntu, and 14.04 specifically, on some *really* old hardware. If you've already spent the money, it's free to try Ubuntu on it, and I expect it will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am pretty positive it will run pretty well. I do have 3d graphics on my card so no worry there. More looking for a peace of mind than anything.

Comment: Dropped the new CPU in, created a new partition for Ubuntu using Easeus, popped iso dvd in and took hardly any time at al and I was up and running. Loaded a new driver for the graphics card and it is running like a champ. Ubuntu needs to really go after this market. I took a severely outdated computer, spent $100 and boom have everything I need for a few more years.

Answer (score 1):

You should have no performance problems with such a system to run Ubuntu.

> Ubuntu Desktop 11.04 and up uses Unity as the default GUI while the
>   previous releases used GNOME Panel by default. In order to run Unity
>   the system needs a more capable graphics adapter – see more here or
>   below:
>
> - 1000 ΜHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
> - 1024 MiB RAM (system memory)
> - 3D Acceleration Capable Videocard with at least 256 MB
>
> From experience, we all know that it is recommended to have 2048 MiB
>   RAM to properly run a day to day Ubuntu.
>
> A good start should be with minimum 1024 and recommended 2048 MiB RAM.

Soucre: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

Answer (score 0):

If your computer satisfies the following requirements the Ubuntu will comfortably work in your comp.

1. 700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
2. 512 MiB RAM (system memory)
3. 5 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)
4. VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
5. Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media
6. Internet access is helpful

If you still have doubts then go for the virtual machine first.

Comment: These are the old requirements for Ubuntu without Unity.

Comment: 14.04 Unity won't run without 3D acceleration, and Unity 2D isn't part of 14.04.