# Installation Errors

Tags: boot, usb-installation

I know that there may be questions already asked and answered relating to this problem, but I don't see them.

I am trying to resurrect my old desktop system by switching to Linux.  But after using UNetbootin to make a bootable USB Key w/Ubuntu 14.04.  (I have used 2 other programs to make a bootable USB Key with bot Ubuntu 12.04 & 14.04)  I get several errors either way that say that it could be a dirty DVD, and I need to clean it and try again. Or it locks up and won't let me install.  However it allows me to boot into a LiveCD session.  As I write this, Firefox keeps crashing, and is starting act just like running my current corrupted version of WinXP.

I went to the website to get a Install DVD, but they are only available in 64bit, I need a 32bit install CD.
 So, my question is: what is the best program to make a USB Key?  Or, how can I get a better Install disk that won't crash?

Comment: What are your hardware specifications? For USB the suggested application on windows is http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows. Install ISOs (for DVD) are available as 32bit -> http://releases.ubuntu.com/trusty/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso but first look at the system requirements (http://askubuntu.com/a/468294/265974). Perhaps Lubuntu or Xubuntu are the better choice!

Comment: My system is a Gigabyte "Socket A" type m-board, w/AMD Athlon XP3200+ cpu, 3GB DDR400 RAM, ATI Raidion 1300+ video card, HHD1 is 80GB, HHD2 is 160 GB.  HHD1 has 2 partitions, 36GB(OS) & 40GB(apps/games); the 2nd partition is where I want to install Linux, but the only option it gives me is to my 2nd HHD (which is data backup).  Which I guess is fine, until I want to get rid of Windows altogether.
 System was in 2003, but have upgraded it over the years. The last time was in 2010, to it's current state.  It has 2 optical drives, a CD-RW drive and a CD-RW/DVD drive.

Comment: The CD-RW drives was faulty and was constantly crashing my system; but I didn't know that at the time. So I turned the system off and only used my new laptop for the last 4 years. I now want to resurrect this old thing w/Linux. I took out the CD-RW drive and since then it has been running a little better, but still crashes. So I re-installed WinXP PRO only to find out it's not supported and I can't get all the updates it needs to run smooth.  
 So I try to install Ubuntu and I get install errors, like:
 /usr/bin/Xorg
 /usr/sbin/unity-greater
 /usr/share/apport

Comment: I don't remember the others I've seen, but I hope this gives you a clue. From your personal experiance, which distro is best suited to me? ver 14.04 or 12.04LTS?
I'm also thinking of trying something else like LinuxMint.

Comment: I would try [Xubuntu 14.04 32bit LTS](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/14.04/release/xubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso). Verify your iso after download -> [HowToMD5SUM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM). If your DVD drive is working use it to install.